# WP_Query and pagination AGAIN?

Tags: wp-query, pagination, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I am using the WP_Query class to retrieve some posts according to variables set in url.

All working well until we get to paging. The second page (though having posts - tested it by making paged => 2) throws a 404. How can I fix this?

Note: Unusual method of getting author(director) data due to method of adding that content in backend.

```
<?php /* GET STUFF */

$director_id = get_query_var('author');
$reel = get_query_var('reel');
$info = get_query_var('info');
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;


$director_args = array(
                    'meta_key' => '_metabox_director',
                    'meta_value' => $director_id,
                    'paged' => $page,
                    'types' => $reel,
                    'posts_per_page' => 2, 
                    'post_type' => 'clip',
                    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
        );  

//query_posts($director_args);
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query($director_args);

if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : ?>


    <?php next_posts_link('Next' ); ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link('Back' ); ?>

    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

            <!-- Loop the loop -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>




<?php endif; ?>
```

Url vars on initial view are `?author=2&reel=commercials` and on second page `?author=2&reel=commercials?paged=2` but the query won't display the posts.

Thanks!

Comment: Got a few questions Niels - Do you have permalinks on? and how is the link being created, by typing it in the address bar or using one of wordpress's functions?

Comment: Permalinks are set to default. Link is generated by `next_posts_link()`. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

`&reel=commercials?paged=2`

That's the problem at the end of that query string. You can't start a query string twice so that `?paged=2` bit is being read as part of the `reel` parameter's value. The question mark should be another **`&`** eg:

`?author=2&reel=commercials&paged=2`

Comment: Which causes one to ask: *how is that query var being appended*? WordPress core functions handle this automatically, which has me curious about the implementation.

Comment: True, I assumed @niels-oeltjen was typing it in on the end to test ie. "making paged => 2". It may be that permalinks are currently off hence the query string.

Comment: Oops, that's a typo. The correct string is `?author=2&reel=commercials&paged=2`. Permalinks are set to default. Link is generated by `next_posts_link()`

Comment: Also, the template being called for the initial view is author.php if that helps at all :-/

Comment: Just to clarify the note in my question regarding retrieving Director content. In the post editor the Director is assigned to the post using a metabox. The user ID of the Director is then retrieved and that is then used to retrieve associated content.